# When I click on a check box in header all the below checkbox should be checked

Tags: javascript, asp.net

[image]

My code is

```
function CheckAll(oCheckbox)
 {
 var GridView2 = document.getElementById("<%=dgShiftOverrideData.ClientID %>");
         for (i = 1; i < ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgShiftOverrideData.rows.length; i++)
 {
             ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgShiftOverrideData.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].checked = oCheckbox.checked;
  }
}

<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Delete" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                                                       <HeaderTemplate>
                                                           <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3"  Checked="false" onclick="CheckAll(this)" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
                                                       </HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete_SO" runat="server"  />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="SentinelGridHeader" />
                                                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localised guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 0):

To just check child checkboxes use this

```
function CheckAll(oCheckbox)
{
("<%=dgShiftOverrideData.ClientID %>").find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
if (this != oCheckbox) {this.checked = oCheckbox.checked;}
});
}
```

Please refer this link 
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Check-Uncheck-all-CheckBoxes-in-ASPNet-GridView-using-jQuery.aspx

I have created below working aspx page you can get idea for this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <script>

                function CheckAll(oCheckbox) {
                    $("#<%= dgShiftOverrideData.ClientID%>").find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
                        if (this != oCheckbox) { this.checked = oCheckbox.checked; }
                    });
                }

            </script>

            <asp:DataGrid ID="dgShiftOverrideData" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" Width="100%" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Delete" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" Checked="false" onclick="CheckAll(this)" runat="server" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete_SO" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="SentinelGridHeader" />
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
                </Columns>
            </asp:DataGrid>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Changes done in your code:

- Removed Autopostback = true from checkbox
- Added Jquery

Comment: Hi i am geeting this error 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: <HeaderTemplate>
                                                           <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3"  Checked="false" onclick="CheckAll(this)" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
                                                       </HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete_SO" runat="server"  />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>

Comment: <asp:DataGrid ID="dgShiftOverrideData" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
                                                OnSortCommand="Sort_Grid_SO" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" OnItemCommand="dgShiftOverrideData_ItemCommand"
                                                OnPageIndexChanged="dgShiftOverrideData_PageIndexChanged" CssClass="Grid" DataKeyField="SOExceptionID">

Comment: I have edited answer with full aspx working code  please let me know if still there  are any issues

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is all you need. It adds a listener to the header checkbox and changes all the other ones when changed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> th input:checkbox").change(function () {
        var is_checked = this.checked;
        $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
            $(this).find("td input:checkbox").each(function (index, element) {
                this.checked = is_checked;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```